# Refactoring a Partial in October CMS

Tags: plugins, refactoring, octobercms

Good day,

I have several partials that have code. In the code tab, I noticed that the code tab had similar looking code. Here are examples

Partial 1

```
function onStart()
{
    $x = MyModel1::where('myColumn', 'myValue')->first();
    // lots of stuff using $x functions
    $this['viewData'] = $x->getViewData();
}
```

Partial 2

```
function onStart()
{
    $x = MyModel2::where('myColumn', 'myValue')->first();
    // lots of stuff using $x functions
    $this['viewData'] = $x->getViewData();
}
```

MyModel1 and MyModel2 both implement the same interface, so they have the same functions.

My question is, where do I put the code that is similar? I can put it in a plugin but that doesn't feel correct. I can create a base class and have the partials call the parent method but won't that mean modifying the code in the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really need to manage your code you can create component and add that code there as they easily attached to other pages (down point is that you need to create a plugin)

you can write your code inside `onRun` method.

https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#page-cycle

and instead directly assigning variables to `this` you need to assign them like

```
$this->page['var'] = 'value';
```

and now it will work same as you are doing.

Comment: It only feels "wrong" to me, because it make my plugin dependent on another plugin. It feels like the first step to dependency hell.

Comment: why do you need other plugin you can dedicate that plugin for this stuff only and do not use this plugin for other stuff, because almost all themes are dependent on some plugins in store , blog, static pages etc ..(dependent means we are reusing code), if we handle it correctly you don't need to worry about it.